# What's the difference between "over and over again" and "again and again"?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between "over and over again" and "again and again"? Are there any subtle hues in meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "over and over again" has a slightly more negative connotation, in that the repetitive behavior is both undesirable and unnecessary.

But the difference is *very* subtle, and either expression would serve in the majority of situations.